# 2's Complement Bitwise Subtraction, Accounting for Zero Case

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

[Part of a HW question]

Assume 2's complement, 32bit word-length. Only signed int and constants 0 through 0xFF allowed. I've been asked to implement a logical right shift by "n" bits (0 <= n <= 31) using ONLY the operators:
! ~ & ^ | + << >>

I figured I could store and clear the sign bit, perform the shift, and replace the stored sign bit in its new location.

I would like to implement the operation "31 - n" (w/out using the "-" operator) to find the appropriate location for the stored sign bit post shift.

If n were positive, I could use the expression: "31 + (~n + 1)", but I don't believe this will work in the case when n = 0.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n) {
/* Store & clear sign bit, perform shift, and replace stored sign bit
   in new location */  
int bit = (x >> 31) & 1; // Store most significant bit
x &= ~(1 << 31); // Clear most significant bit
x = x >> n; // Shift by n
x &= ~((~bit) << (31 - n)); // Replace MSbit in new location

return x;
}
```

Any help and/or hints are appreciated.

Comment: The last operation should probably be an or, not an and.

Comment: Why don't you just make an arithmetic shift and clear the high bits?

Comment: If you are ok to code in current standard C, or any previous versions of standard C, you can just cast it to unsigned int, then shift, then cast it back. Or go straight old-school and write inline assembly.

Comment: @MikeMB Can't use any constants larger than 0xFF. Would this sort of mask be possible with that restriction?

Comment: the limitation on operators makes it tricky but still you can do `return (x+0u)>>n;`

Comment: @user3528438 Can't use any form of casting.

Comment: no, no casting (no casting operators), no large constants, standard C99 code, try it here: https://ideone.com/eHEoBL

Comment: @user3528438 Thank you. That does work. Unfortunately, the only data type I can use is signed int. Tried not to go into all the restrictions in the post ...

Comment: It may be easier to look at it in a different way. Rather than removing the sign bit to prevent the sign propagation from the arithmetic shift, why don't you just shift it and then remove all the shifted in bits instead.  Surely there's an easy way to create a mask of the bits to keep.

Comment: You might get better answers on electronics stack exchange despite being a programming question.  Software engineers are going to tell you how to do this in software but you are trying to model hardware!

Comment: `31 + (~n + 1)` actually works when `n=0`.

Comment: @user3528438 You're right, I was overthinking it. Thanks again.

Comment: Even if one assumes "2's complement,", `1 << 31` is _still_ undefined behavior and a compiler that uses 2's complement `int` may still not create the hoped for code.  Such tricks are better suited for assembly code than C.  Since OP answered in the question (a no-no on stack-overflow, just make your own answer,) nothing left but to DV.

Comment: @chux Sorry, guess I missed that in the guidelines ... I'll move it to an answer.

Comment: @chux is the bit representation of `1 << 31` (what we're after here) undefined ?

Comment: @sgoldburg Yes, for 32-bit `int`, `1 << 31` is UB  (§6.5.7 11 4).  Code this and someday in the future when code fails, you may recall this.  Use unsigned math like ``1u << 31`

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: Solved]

Thanks to everyone for the help. ~n + 1 works to negate n in this situation, including for the case n = 0 (where it returns 0 as desired). Functional code is below (by no means the most elegant solution). Utility operations borrowed from: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c?rq=1)

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n) {
/* Store & clear sign bit, perform shift, and replace stored sign bit
   in new location */
int bit = (x >> 31) & 1; // Store most significant bit
x &= ~(1 << 31); // Clear most significant bit
x = x >> n; // Shift by n
x ^= ((~bit + 1) ^ x) & (1 << (31 + (~n + 1))); // Replace MSbit in new location

return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n) {
    return (x >> n) ^ (((x & 0x80000000) >> n) << 1);
}
```

Sadly, using the constant `0x80000000` is forbidden. We could calculate it as `1 << 31` (ignoring undefined behavior in C) or, to save on instruction, calculate `31 - n` as `n ^ 31` and then use the following somewhat more contrived method:

```
int logicalShift(int x, int n) {
    int b = 1 << (n ^ 31);
    return b ^ ((x >> n) + b);
}
```

Comment: `0x80 * 0x10 * 0x10 * 0x10 * 0x10 * 0x10 * 0x10`?

Comment: My assumption was that this is about some abstract machine model with limited instructions (e.g. no `*`) that happens to be expressed as C expressions (so the exact semantics of C don't matter), and that we're trying to minimize the number of operations.

Comment: Oh, wait. You could do `0x80 << 24` but that would have undefined behavior like `1<<31` does.

Comment: Assuming two's complement, you could do (-(1 << 30)) ^ (1 << 30).

Comment: But `-` isn't allowed. Oh well.

Comment: Whoops. Harder than I thought. Best I can do is `~1 ^ (~(1 << 30) << 1)`.